# Python web scraping "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, web-scraping, indexing, soap

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\dylan\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe")
data_list=[]


site = requests.get('https://www.visitnh.gov/things-to-do/food-and-drink/restaurants')

if site.status_code is 200:
   content = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
   Resultswrapper = content.find_all('div', attrs={'results-wrapper'})

for Results in Resultswrapper:
    print("Random phrase: ")
    #print(Results.select(class_='results-wrapper').prettify())
    BusinessName = Results.select('.item-title.ng-binding')[0].get_text()
    Address =   Results.select('.ng-binding')[0].get_text()
    PhoneNumber = Results.select('.ng-binding')[0].get_text()
    new_data = {"BusinessName": BusinessName, "Address": Address, "PhoneNumber": PhoneNumber}
    data_list.append(new_data)
    print("data: " + data_list)
    print("new data: " + new_data)

with open ('find.csv','w') as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["BusinessName", "Address", "PhoneNumber"], delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data_list:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I get an index out of range error when trying to make a simple web scraper and I'm trying to loop using a selector. I use this URL: https://www.visitnh.gov/things-to-do/food-and-drink/restaurants

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/dylan/Documents/Webscrape/web-s.py", line 19, in <module>
BusinessName = Results.select('p.item-title.ng-binding')[0].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried change the result wrapper to something different in the HTMl but its not the same. I also tried messing around with the text in the select, but no use. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL via javascript. You can use `requests`/`json` module to simulate this request:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.visitnh.gov/BusinessListingService.asmx/GetUsers'
search_params = {"searchParams":{"ResultsPerPage":15,"BusinessType":"attraction","SubcategoryID":25}}
data = json.loads(requests.post(url, json=search_params).json()['d'])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for result in data['Results']:
    print(result['BusinessName'])
    print(result['Address'])
    print(result['Phone'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
NazBar & Grill
1086 Weirs Blvd, Laconia, NH 03246
(603) 366-4341
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Giant of Siam
5 E Hollis Street, Nashua, NH 03060
(603) 595-2222
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hobbs Tavern & Brewing Company
2415 NH Route 16, Ossipee, NH 03890
(603) 539-2000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on. (Total 164 items.)
```

Comment: Im getting 'request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'''

Comment: @Brogrammer Do you use `requests.post()`? What version of `requests` are you using? I'm on `requests==2.24.0`

Comment: I believe I am using 2.0.0

Comment: @Brogrammer Try to upgrade the `requests` module. Version 2.0.0 is from 2013 https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/community/updates/#id61

Comment: How do I find the correct search parameters of any website I want, say a job searching website?

Comment: @Brogrammer Every site is different (there isn't any ONE correct approach). But what I do is open Firefox developer tools -> Network tab and watch, where the page is making requests (assuming the page loads the data from external URLs).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, you can see that the element you are trying to select is not present when the document is first ready. The list of restaurants on this website is inserted into the page later, which is why your script cannot find it right away.

Maybe wait a bit before selecting with the built in [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) function.